# Terminal sandbox commands

Tags: shell, terminal, php, sandbox

I was wondering if there's a way to run shell commands that affect only a certain directory and its subdirectories.

I'm using PHP and I want to make an app that allows the user to execute shell commands from a web page, but I want these commands to be restricted to a directory only

Answer (score 3):

Avoid running any commands on your host machine originating from a web page. That's a recipe for disaster.

Have a look at [operating system level virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization). Depending on your OS you can use [zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_Containers), [jails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail) or [LXC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC).

Those OS level instances have a very low overhead and can be fired up pretty quickly. They do provide separation between the host OS and the user's environment. It's not as safe as a fully virtualized machine, but it might be sufficient for your use case.